# Bootstrap and nested rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap to make the style of my webpage.

I want to do something similar to this image:
[image]

I have been trying it (in the snipped you can test it), but I don't know if it is the best way to do it.

I mean that **i'm not sure if is correct** to add two divs without any data on it (col-xs-2), only to add some spaces (columns of bootstrap) to the left and to the right.

Is there a better way to do that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:white;>
     <div class="row" >
       <div class="col-xs-12">WEB LOGO------------------------</div> 
       <div class="row"> 
          <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color:white;"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-8" style="background-color:grey;">YES</div>
          <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color:white;"></div>
       </div>
       <span> more content here -------------</span>
     </div>
  </div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the empty div's you can use an [offset](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting):

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2" style="background-color:grey;">YES</div>
```

This will move your element 2 columns to the right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `style="inline-block"` inside of the parent div you want the children to fall inline in.